# Erro de AppClash (KERNELBASE.DLL) quando DLL em Delphi tenta mostrar mensagem em aplicação Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, kernel

Tenho uma DLL feita em Delphi XE7 que é chamada por aplicação feita Delphi também na versão XE7.

Essa DLL não necessita que seja registrada no Windows.

Que, quando falta alguma informação ou ao entrar em uma exceção tratada, a DLL mostra uma mensagem (ShowMessage) para usuário do que deu de errado ou faltando.

Em computadores que tem Windows XP, 7 e 10 (32 e 64 bits). Mesmo a DLL e aplicação estando em rede, está mostrando essas mensagens corretamente.

Mas instalando em rede em Windows Server 2012 r2, ao tentar mostrar essas mensagens está ocorrendo erro de APPCRASH, KernelBase.dll.

Quando não há necessidade de mostrar alguma mensagem, a DLL funciona perfeitamente.

Dei uma pesquisada, verifiquei que problemas de permissão de acesso, se não estou enganado. Mas a DLL não funciona quando é necessário mostra alguma mensagem.

Alguém têm alguma ideia para resolver isso?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, se puder dar uma revisada no texto agradeço. Quanto a dll, o windows tem um [mecanismo de ordem de procura](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) de dlls. É fortemente aconselhado para que você deixe essas dlls na mesma pasta da aplicação, e se o problema for em relação a permissão, executar a aplicação como administrador.

Comment: Resumindo; a DLL mostra mensagens para o usuário, mas quando o S.O. é Windows Server R2 está dando erro APPCrash. E sim, a DLL está na pasta de aplicação e é executada como administrador.

Comment: Como foi declarada a dll, e como estão sendo as chamadas. Esse [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581142/why-is-this-process-crashing-as-soon-as-it-is-launched) fala um pouco sobre isso também e uma possível solução caso seja o mesmo problema.